# JAVASCRIPT: ml5.js: Initialization of backend webgl failed t.initializeBackend @ tf-core.esm.js:17

Tags: javascript, tensorflow, webgl, ml5.js

I get this 'warning' (running on the cpu because you couldn't use the gpu is a bit of a step up from 'warning yellow'... much more of a 'danger orange' if you ask me) when trying to run the following code:

```
<html>
    <body id="root"></body>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/ml5@0.4.3/dist/ml5.min.js"></script>
    <script src="app.js"></script>
</html>
```

app.js

```
const root = document.getElementById('root');
const canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
console.log('ml5 version:', ml5.version);
```

however the webgl test-page works just fine: I see a spinning cube.

My setup is as follows:

```
 Chrome:  Version 86.0.4240.111 (Official Build) (64-bit);
 OS: Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS
```

I am unsure of what could be causing just tensor flow to be unable to find webgl?

When hardware acceleration is turned on, the flag is set, and the webgl test works...

As well as every non-ml5.js webgl example I have found so far.

The p5 examples for ml5.js also fail to grab a webgl context, I've tried firefox too.

/Any ideas?/ is this a bug in ml5 ?/is linux not supported by tensorflow/ml5 ?/